# $inc with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

First, I want to apologize for my bad english.

I have a Schema that looks like this:

```
var playerSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true, index: { unique: true } },
    wood: { type: Number, required: true, default: 500 },
    woodPerHour: { type: Number, required: true, default: 3600 }
});
```

And I want to increment to 'wood' a quantity of 'woodPerHour'/3600 each second. The problem is that using $inc, i can't add a quantity based on a schema value. That's how it looks right now (I'm adding 1 for test).

```
playerModel.update({}, {$inc:{wood:1}}, function(err){
        if(err) console.log("error al update: " + err);
    });
```

There is a smart way to do it or I have to do a find({}) and then forEach?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow first of all! Secondly, this site is mainly designed to help you overcome programming problems when you hit a rough spot and can't get past it. To get high quality answers, be sure to post what you've tried, what result you're currently getting, and what the desired result is. Be sure to include all of that for the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to use find({}):
eg.

```
playerModel.find({}, function(err,records){
    if(err) console.log("error trying to update ");
    for(var i in records) {
       records[i].wood++; // Or some calc
       records[i].save();
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use update as you said. You need to do that with simple iteration.

```
playerModel.find({}, function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        data.wood = data + data.woodPerHour/3600; //update as you want
        data.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error occured while updating doc: " + data._id);
            } else {
                console.log("Doc updated: " + data._id);
            }
        })
    } else {
        console.log("Error occured while iterationg");
    }
})
```